# Render edits made to .cs file without building the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sitefinity

I am trying to make some changes to an existing asp.net website made in sitefinity cms. I am editing a .cs file but it does not changes anything on the website.

I cannot build this website in visual studio because it keeps on giving me the errors while building no matter how many errors I solve.

There is link [forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/1768003.aspx?Change+in+a+cs+file+require+rebuild+of+website+or+not+) which says that rebuilding the project is not required for websites made in asp.net. Building is only required in web applications where dll files are created.

If its true then the changes should render and show up on website. Am I missing something?

Comment: If a project has its own library (which it probably has) then the cs files will be compiled in a dll file. So if you make changes you need to recompile and upload the new dlll

Comment: Which sitefinity version you are using, also can you give more detail on what file you have changed in the solution ?

Comment: Its sitefinity 8.2 and I am editing a custom widget for which I need to make some changes to the .cs files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After alot of hit and trial I have found that you can render the changes without building an asp.net website. In my case I changed the CodeBehind attribute to CodeFile and changes done only on the ascx and cs files started showing.

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinity is a .NET web application not a website which uses Just in time compilation (JIT).  In order to see changes reflected to a CS file you have to build the project or solution.

Comment: You are wrong. In case of website you don't need to build a solution to render the changes. Building is only required in case of web applications

Comment: @ShujaatShaikh As I stated in my answer Sitefinity IS a Web Application not a website, so not sure how this is wrong.

Comment: R sorry because i already mentioned in my question that i have a sitefinity website